# strange IDE in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my VS2015 there is a strange HTML tree nodes view of my MVC View.  This tree nodes view occupies 1/4 of the screen all the time.  I don't know what addon I added.  There is no way to dismiss it.  Does any know?

[image]

Comment: What extensions do you have installed?

Comment: That's what I am trying to figure out.  I added several.

Comment: If you can't list them, I don't see how we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by disable the suspected add-on one at a time until the problem goes away.  Interestingly, when I re-enable each of the disabled add-on, the problem goes away without removing any add-on.